# How to use list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to write a program that retrieves user input for sales for every weekday and then calculates the total. What I have got so far looks like this.

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

index = 0

def sales_by_days(days):
while index < len(days)
sales1 = float(input("Enter sales for", days[0], "here. "))
// then repeat for the rest of the elements //
index += 1
totalsales = sales1 + sales2 + sales3 + sales4 + sales5
print ("Your total sales for the week are", totalsales, ". ")`
```

It's not really having the desired results. Can anybody give me some pointers on where I am going wrong?

Comment: That's not Python. I'd recommend a basic tutorial: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. Also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop instead of `while` loop here,

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

def sales_by_days(days):
    totalsales = 0
    for day in days:
        sales = float(input(f"Enter sales for {day} here. "))
        totalsales += sales
    print(f"Your total sales for the week are {totalsales} .")
```

Execution:

```
Enter sales for Monday here. 10
Enter sales for Tuesday here. 2
Enter sales for Wednesday here. 4
Enter sales for Thursday here. 6
Enter sales for Friday here. 8
Your total sales for the week are 30.0 .
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to receive user input for each day's sales and calculate the sum, you must either add to a global variable *total sales* on every loop iteration or store each of the sales in a global list variable *sales* and take its sum afterwards.

```
# Your solution modified
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
index = 0
total_sales = 0
def sales_by_days(days):
    while index < len(days):
        total_sales += float(input("Enter sales for", days[index], "here. "))
        index += 1
    print ("Your total sales for the week are", total_sales, ". ")`
```

OR

```
# Maybe a cleaner, simpler solution
def sales_by_days():
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
    total = 0
    for day in days:
        total += float(input("Enter sales for ", day, " here."))
    print("Your total sales for the week are ", total_sales, ".")`
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain academic integrity, I have approached the problem in a different manner. However, the process (and learning) should remain similar and consequently this response should be useful.

```py
sales_quantity = {'monday': 0.0, 'tuesday': 0.0, 'wednesday': 0.0, 'thursday': 0.0, 'friday': 0.0, 'saturday': 0.0, 'sunday': 0.0}

for day in sales_quantity.keys():
    sales_quantity[day] = round(float(input("Enter the sales quantity for " + day + ": ")), 2) 

for day, quantity in sales_quantity.items():
    print(f"The sales quantity for {day} is {str(quantity)}")

total_quantity = sum(sales_quantity.values())

print(f"The total quantity this week is {total_quantity}")
```

The dictionary `sales_quantity` contains an 'attribute' of keys and values. You may invoke the `.keys()` or `.values()` of any dictionary to return the "dict_keys" or "dict_values" object. This object may be iterated through in an identical manner of a list object. The advantage of using a dictionary over two separate lists, however, is the interlinking of the lists with a single object.

In the `for day in sales_quantity.keys()`, you are iterating through the de-facto 'list' (really the type dict_keys). You assign each of the individual instances to the variable `day`.

The `round(val, 2)` is used to clean the input. Otherwise, a user may input unreasonable values.

The `sales_quantity[day] = var` is used to alter the data into the dictionary.

The `print(f"` indicates to use the format print method. This allows you to embed variables easily.